# Cakephp 3 image upload how to save file name from model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to save file name in model.

I already implemented code to upload file in model using below code

```
$validator 
      ->add('image',[
                    'mimeType' => [
                        'rule'    => ['mimeType',['image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg']],
                        'message' => 'Please upload only jpg and png.',
                        'last' => true,
                    ],
                    'processImageUpload'=>[
                        'rule'     => 'processImageUpload',
                        'provider' => 'table',
                        'message'  => 'Unable to process cover image upload.',
                    ],
      ]);

      return $validator;
```

In processImageUpload I want save file name. But name is not saving

```
public function processImageUpload($check = array()) {

           // upload file code here working fine

            $this->image = 'uploads/'. $check['name']; //not working
            return TRUE;
}
```

How can I save image name in image field from my model method ?

version : 3.8.4

Comment: First in your from accept only jpg/png https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp, to prevent selecting other file types,  then for malicious user simple check before patchEntity if mime type jpg/png return true, else false . Then something like if ($isAcceptable && $this->Users->save($user)) ...

Comment: buildRules event  can solve your problem https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#buildrules